# how to print 20 lines at a time from a large string?

Tags: c, linux, command

So i have this program that reads a file. and it reads it into this massive string called `accepting[900000]` now the thing is, that i need to display the contents inside of the file 20 lines at a time like when you are using the more command. my question is what command is it possible to use in order to perform something like `exelp("more", "more", "-20", NULL)?` I need to display the contents 20 lines at a time and show the next 20 lines by having the user push space. please help me! many thanks.

Comment: you stored the entire file contents into a single string of 900K, allocated on the stack?

Comment: it's a desparate measure

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Don't know how you're waiting to user input so you'll have to fill it in.

```
int print_20_lines(char* accepting, int current_index)
{
    int idx = current_index;
    int num_lines = 0;
    for(;accepting[idx] != '\0' && num_lines < 20;idx++) {
        if(accepting[idx] == '\n') 
            num_lines++;
    }

    printf("%.*s", idx-current_index, accepting+current_index);
    
    if(accepting[idx] == '\0')
        return -1;
    else
        return idx;
}


void print_20_lines_a_time_with_each_user_input(char* accepting)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while(idx != -1) {
        idx = print_20_lines(accepting, idx);
        wait_for_space();
    }
}
```

BTW, `accepting[900000]` is going to hit the maximum stack size on both Windows and Linux quite soon. Adding a 0 to the end will likely crash your program.

Comment: I really appreciate your response but by any chance is there a port to port the contents into like the "more" command similarly to what i was talking about like initially?

Comment: Not really. `more` is a 2000 line program that uses VT100 control sequences and a lot of POSIX API to handle screen scrolling. It would take at minimum days to replicate the functionality.